# Is it possible to POST zipped XML to topic in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

Will the [ActiveMQ REST interface](https://activemq.apache.org/rest) support zipped XML messages when posting to topics? I'm not able to test this myself right now.

Comment: Did you read the manual ?

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, ActiveMQ doesn't care about the *content* of the message. It's all just bytes. Assuming the message doesn't fail for some other indirectly related reason (e.g. it exceed the max frame size) then it should work.